# Calculated values on chart

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to print the previous high and low prices of a candle below and on top the next one?

I'd also like to know how to place calculated values on the chart, is this possible?
Thanks

```
study(title = "HiLo Last Candle", shorttitle = "HiLO", overlay=true) 
h=high[1] 
plotchar(h,text=tostring(h, 0.0),location=location.abovebar)
```

Comment: That's probably possible but what have you tried so far? Add some code examples to your post after reading this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I tried this but received an error code . study(title = "HiLo Last Candle", shorttitle = "HiLO", overlay=true)


h=high[1]

plotchar(h,text=tostring(h, 0.00),location=location.abovebar)

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, it's better to edit your question and include the code so it's nice and readable.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to print values on the chart yet.

To put calculated values on the chart users usually use `overlay=true` param of the study function:

```
//@version=3
study(title = "MyStudy", overlay=true) 
plot(sma(close, 7))
```

And it seems you're familiar with this approach.
Another way is to "create" your own chart using `plotcandle`/`plotbar` functions, where you can create bars by yourself:

```
//@version=3
study(title = "MyStudy") 

len = input(title="sma length", type=integer, minval=1, maxval=100, defval=7)
close_sma = sma(close, len)
open_sma = sma(open, len)
high_sma = sma(high, len)
low_sma = sma(low, len)

actual_high = max(close_sma, max(open_sma, max(high_sma, low_sma)))
actual_low = min(close_sma, min(open_sma, min(high_sma, low_sma)))

plotcandle(open_sma, actual_high, actual_low, close_sma, color = close_sma > open_sma ? green : red)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("HL of previous bar",overlay=true)
h = label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(high[1]), 
     color=color.green, 
     textcolor=color.white,
     style=label.style_labeldown, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
label.delete(h[1]) // remove the previous label when new bar appears  

l = label.new(bar_index, na, tostring(low[1]), 
     color=color.red, 
     textcolor=color.white,
     style=label.style_labelup, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
label.delete(l[1]) // remove the previous label when new bar appears
```

Comment: always add descriptive answer to help other user to understand.